# Отправка post запроса

Tags: c#, post

Помогите отправить post запрос на c#, ниже скрин снифера с запросом.!

[image]

Comment: Отправил. Помог. Что дальше? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Реализация POST-запроса через RestSharp.

```
public void DoPOSTRequest(CookieContainer cookies, string subUrl)
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("// адрес хоста //")
            {
                UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1", 
                FollowRedirects = true, 
                CookieContainer = cookies  
            };

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("// подадрес //", Method.POST);

            Parameter param = new Parameter // создаем параметр
            {
                Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost, // тип параметра
                Name = name, //имя параметра
                Value = value //значение параметра
            };

            request.AddParameter(param); //добавлени параметра в запрос

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); // отправка запроса
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [эту](http://blog.foolsoft.ru/c-funkcii-post-i-get-zaprosov-gotovye-k-primen/) ссылу. Кстаи первая в поиске гугла.